# "can't find the specified file" error, when I debug a program

Tags: c, file, printf, stdio

I was writing a very basic program that print on a .txt file the number 10,
the problem occurs when I try to debug it, Visual Studio shows me an error window "can't find the specified file". (it's written in C)

Here's my code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    
    int main() {
        FILE* f = fopen("file.txt", "w"); 
        if (f == NULL) {
            exit(1);
        } 
        int number = 10; 
        fprintf(f, "a number: %d\n", number); 
    
        fclose(f); 
    
        return 0; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the flag `"w+"` in `fopen` to create the file if it does not exist yet.